# In Java, what is the difference between using the toString method vs explicit String casting vs plus quotes (ex. myObj+"")?

Tags: java, casting, jvm

What is the difference between plus quotes (+"") and using a "toString()" method or even explicitly casting with something like `(String) myObject`? Trade-offs?

```
myObject.toString()
```

vs.

```
myObject+""
```

or even vs.

```
(String) myObject
```

More specifically, is there any time using the `myObj+""` method can get you into trouble?

**Edited for clarity**

**EDIT 2:**

Seems `String.valueOf(myObj);` is the prefered method for avoiding a null pointer. That said: Is there ever a time when the following is false?

```
String.valueOf(myObj).equals(myObj+"")
```

Comment: This link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgGAUGC9ksk (from 11:30) compares the difference in performance of the various ways to convert an `int` to a `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Java 7, if you want to avoid a NullPointerException, you can simply use one of these:

```
Objects.toString( myObject )
Objects.toString( myObject, "defaultValueWhenMyObjectIsNull" )
```

In all versions of Java, the first of these can also be accomplished with the following, as noted by @NobuGames in the first comment below:

```
String.valueOf( myObject )
```

The mechanisms you cite each has a flaw.

```
 myObject.toString()  // throws NullPointerException if myObject is null.
 myObject+""          // Hack; impairs understandability.
 (String) myObject    // throws ClassCastException unless myObject is a String or null
```

**EDIT (after question edit)**

> is there any time using the myObj+"" method can get you into trouble?

Yes, you can confuse other programmers. The intent of the hack is not clear. This can lead to increased cost in time, and increased risk of someone "fixing" it.

However, in terms of just the compiler, you're fine. From the [Java Language Specification, section 15.18: String concatentation operator +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

And from that cited section [5.1.11: String conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> - If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
> - Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the toString method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the toString method is null, then the string "null" is used instead.

This second case leads to a difference that you asked about.

> Is there ever a time when the following is false? `String.valueOf(myObj).equals(myObj+"")`

No, but there's a time when that throws a NullPointerException. When `myObj` is a non-null reference to an object whose `toString()` method returns null, then `String.valueOf(myObj)` will be null. Calling the equals method will throw the NullPointerException.

But I suspect you're asking whether there's ever a time the two have different values. Yes, they can have different values. `Objects.toString()` and `String.valueOf()` can return null values. The hack will always have a non-null value.

That said, returning null from `toString()` is somewhat bad form. The JLS acknowledges that it can happen, but the API implies that it should not. Personally, if I were concerned about this case, I would handle it in some way other than the hack.

Comment: And before Java 8 `String.valueOf(myObject)` will do

Comment: Any reason to use these methods over +""? That's what I'm actually interested in. The explicit cast part of the question was more of an after thought.

Comment: I'm not sure why you consider throwing NullPointerException a flaw.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - because the OP specifically stated that he or she is trying to avoid NullPointerException.

Comment: I clearly worded my question too conversationally. Sorry about that. I really want to know if there is any time using `myObj+""` can get you in trouble. The bit about null pointers was just an aside.

Comment: Great answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
myObject+""
```

Is translated by the compiler to this:

```
new StringBuilder().append(myObject).append("").toString()
```

The `StringBuilder` append method does a null check on the input argument, appending the text "null".

The `String` class has an overloaded `valueOf` method, so you can also do:

```
String.valueOf(myObject)
```

Which will do a null check, returning the text "null".

Comment: Nice decomposing what that line of code actually gets turned into.

Comment: So it seems `x+""` and `String.valueOf(x)` return the same thing (in all cases?), Is there any reason, apart from readability, to use one or the other?

Comment: Yes, they do. `x + ""` goes through a few more steps (through a `StringBuilder`), while `String.valueOf` is more direct in expressing intent and in its implementation. That sounds like a win for `String.valueOf` to me.

Answer (score 0):

Casting to String is going to be highly contextual, so more than one technique may apply here. If you are expecting to directly cast to String, my advice would be to prepare for it. If there is a chance it can be null, then check for it. Or make the API promise not to hand you a null. That is, this is a separation of concerns and a layering of responsibilities.

However, IMO, any sufficiently complicated class ought to have a `toString()` method. It can be for debugging, or used as a property for computation, but it ought to be human readable. There are few cases where a human-readable version of the object is not warranted, in my experience.

Relying on overloading the + operator *feels* like a hack, yes.